# How to automate script restart with pm2?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, cron

I have a script which is located on my VPS (Ubuntu 18.04)
I would like to run script forever and I was using PM2. The problem was that sometimes script breaks and I think it's because of memory load. I would like to setup script restarting in terminal.

I try to do it like this: I enter `crontab -e` and I specify it like this `55 * * * * databases.js restartall`

File name is `databases.js`.

When I check with `pm2 list` I saw that there was no restarts, but time was passed. Did I specify query wrongly in crontab?